# If any data duplicate then output show 1 if not then show 0 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Table: `emp`

```
id | name | sal
----------------
 1 | abc  | 100
 2 | ha   | 200
 1 | abc  | 100
 1 | abc  | 100
 1 | abc  | 100
 2 | ha   | 200
 2 | ha   | 200
 3 | hai  | 400
```

Based on this data I want give data duplicate or not in the table for that  status i out show output.

I tried like this:

```
select  
    count(*) as status
from 
    [Test].[dbo].[emp]
group by
    [id], [name], [sal]
having 
    count(*) >= 1
order by 
    count(*) desc
```

I get this output:

```
status
4
3
1
```

I do not want get output like above way.

I want show output like below

```
Status
    1
```

when data comes unique in table that time  **status shows : 0 values.**

1 means duplicate data and o means unique records.please tell me how to get singe status values to achive this issue.

Comment: which version of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
SELECT Id, Name, Sal, COUNT(*) ,
      CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END Status
FROM
(
SELECT 1 Id,  'abc' Name, 100 Sal
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ha', 200
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'abc', 100
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'abc', 100
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'abc', 100
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ha', 200
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'ha', 200
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'hai', 400
) A
GROUP BY Id, Name, Sal
```

Comment: Hi thanks given query.I am expecting output result only one values.that means if any records have duplicate finaly output show one(1) only .no need to display corresponding duplicate values status show 1.If all records unique in that table I want display  only 0(zero).no need to display corresponding unique value status zero(0).please tell me how to achive this.

Comment: SELECT CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1  
        ELSE 0 
        END STATUS, COUNT(*)
FROM 
(
SELECT Id, Name, Sal, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT 1 Id,  'abc' Name, 100 Sal
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'ha', 200
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'abc', 100
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'abc', 100
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'abc', 100
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'ha', 200
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'ha', 200
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'hai', 400
) A
GROUP BY Id, Name, Sal
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) A

Comment: HI I tried above given query.its given error.Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
No column name was specified for column 4 of 'A'.
. i changed count() to count(*) in above query and ran that its given above error

Comment: SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END STATUS
FROM ( 
  SELECT Id, Name, Sal, COUNT(*) FROM ( 
    SELECT 1 Id, 'abc' Name, 100 Sal 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 'ha', 200 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1, 'abc', 100 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1, 'abc', 100 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1, 'abc', 100 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 'ha', 200 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 'ha', 200 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3, 'hai', 400 ) A 
  GROUP BY Id, Name, Sal 
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) A

Comment: replace count() into count(*)

Comment: Hi Tried what you given query repace count() into count(*).its given same error. I did not fine any differece what you given 2 query in comments.please  tell any best solution

Comment: can you share me the query which you are trying plz?

Comment: Hi I tried below query and got above error.SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END STATUS FROM ( SELECT Id, Name, Sal, COUNT(*) FROM ( SELECT 1 Id, 'abc' Name, 100 Sal UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'ha', 200 UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'abc', 100 UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'abc', 100 UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'abc', 100 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'ha', 200 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'ha', 200 UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'hai', 400 ) A GROUP BY Id, Name, Sal HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) A

Comment: I have placed the query in the following link and it works in SQLFiddle.  Please check whether it works for you.. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/5945/0

Comment: Hi its working in Sql Fiddle .but in sql server 20012 version (ssms) its not working and it given error pervious what i posted.please tell me how resolve in ssms(2012 version).

Comment: can you try this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/6270

it works in SQL server 2012

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when c>0 then 1 else 0 end as status from(
select count(*) as c from
(select count(*) as cout from loss
group by loss_claim,loss_key
having count(*)>1)as a) b
```

Comment: Hi thanks given query.I am expecting output result only one values.that means if any records have duplicate finaly output show one(1) only .no need to display corresponding duplicate values status show 1.If all records unique in that table I want display  only 0(zero).no need to display corresponding unique value status zero(0).please tell me how to achive this.

Comment: Hi I have edited query it will give you required result